# How big is AppEngine BlobStore meta-data per entry?

Tags: google-app-engine, size, metadata, blob, blobstore

I'm trying to get a handle on the data-overhead required to store a blob in AppEngine's BlobStore.

Let's say I save a 1KB blob, how many bytes will that cost me in BlobStore and in DataStore respectively?

In other words: How big does an entity need to be, before it's worth it to move it to BlobStore?

Comment: There's some information about datastore metadata here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/storage_breakdown#anc-entitiestable

Comment: What kind of data do you want to store? Choosing blobstore or datastore is a functional consideration. I pref to use the datastore for rather small properties. But when you store small images (icons) using the blobstore you can make use of the High performance Image serving with the blobstore.

Comment: @Adam: Thank you for the link, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to talk about BlobStore.

Comment: @voscausa: Since I just need to store binary data and won't be processing it in any way, there's really no functional difference for me in this case. So, I'm purely optimizing cost here.

Comment: When you store a blob in the blobstore, you always need to save the blob_key in the datastore. You can also store additional properties in a datastore entity. So accessing / querying an entity in the datastore is more easy and will cost less in most cases.

Comment: The "will cost less" part is exactly what I'm concerned about. The $/GB/month is twice as high in DataStore as it is in BlobStore. So, let's say I need to store 2KB. Then, if all the overhead of storing it as a blob in BlobStore amounts to 1KB stored in Datastore, then it's exactly a draw between the cost of putting 2KB in Blobstore and 1KB in Datastore vs. putting 2KB in Datastore. If the overhead is less than 1KB, a 2KB blob is cheaper in BlobStore and if it's more than 1KB, a 2KB blob is cheaper in DataStore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is not documented, but you can do a bit of guess-work to get a minimum overhead per blob.

Each blob created requires a blob info and a blob key. The blob key, I believe, is 500 bytes. The blob-info has a content_type (string), creation time (datetime), filename (string), and size (integer). We can assume that [each string uses 1 more byte than their length](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/storage_breakdown). Also, assuming you do not use the optional file-name or content type field. Then the blob-info items  will be approximately, 1 bytes, 8 bytes, 1 bytes, and 8 bytes, respectively, totaling 18 bytes.

Therefore, **the minimum likely overhead for a blob item will be at least 518 bytes per blob, stored in the datastore.** But we're not done, we still need to figure out the optimal pricing.

Pricing for the blob-store per month will be:

```
= $0.13/G * blob_file_size + 518 bytes * $0.24 / gig 
= blob_file_size/1024/1024*.13 + 0.00011856079
```

Whereas pricing for storage entirely in the datastore is:

```
= blob_file_size/1024/1024*.24
```

**The break-even point where the two cost the same amount is 1130.2 bytes.** Any more and the blobstore will be cheaper, and less and the datastore will be cheaper. Of course, this is based on the minimum overhead of 518 bytes, and I would bet the overhead will often be higher, so maybe a rule of thumb would be 2kb.

Comment: I like the approach. It's probably a little bigger, since I think the blobinfo stores some sort of data hash as well and probably also google-internal stuff for them to more efficiently retrieve the blob. So, I think your estimate of 2KB sounds very reasonable and it's probably the best we'll be able to do without actual docs. Thank you!